# What physically happens inside a computer when a piece of code is compiled and run

Tags: assembly, compilation, operating-system, system-calls, cpu-architecture

I'm curious to understand how a piece of code is transformed into something that the computer can understand. In many similar questions, a common answer is to state that the chain from human readable code to machine level instructions follows more or less the compilation chain:

```
high-level code --> assembly code --> machine binary code
```

Nevertheless the high frequency of this answer, it still remains a bit of mystery to me what really is going on in the computer. I do understand the basic electronics behind the computers and CPUs to some extent, but this particular case is a bit of mystery still to me.

Say for example that I code the classical "Hello, world!" example in

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, world!";
    return 0;
}
```

which is then transformed into the assembly code, like e.g.

```
section     .text
global      _start                              ;must be declared for linker (ld)

_start:                                         ;tell linker entry point

    mov     edx,len                             ;message length
    mov     ecx,msg                             ;message to write
    mov     ebx,1                               ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov     eax,4                               ;system call number (sys_write)
    int     0x80                                ;call kernel

    mov     eax,1                               ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int     0x80                                ;call kernel

section     .data

msg     db  'Hello, world!',0xa                 ;our dear string
len     equ $ - msg                             ;length of our dear string
```

which is ultimately transformed into the binary sequence

```
10100010101001111...................
```

and then "Hello, world!" appears on the screen.

**My question thus is: During this process, what is physically in an electric signal level happening in each stage of this process inside the computer?**

I understand that my question might be too broad to answer fully so I'd be grateful if you could point out the major physical phenomena that happens inside the computer (e.g. between hard drive, CPU and the RAM).

Also, please let me know if my question is off-topic, since it is not always 100% unambiguous where the border between different disciplines of computer engineering lay. In this case, could you suggest another SE site, where this question might be better suited for, thank you.

Comment: "The whole process" is way too broad, you could probably get some starting points by looking up "computer architecture".

Comment: @Mat thank you for pointing this out. What if I change "The whole process" -> "process"? I'm also grateful If I get a partial answer. It would be great if one could get a bit more concrete understanding of what coding is on a real physical level.

Comment: Physically, a billion or so of transistors switch on and off at rate of billions of times a second. It would be impossible to describe what they're all doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A computer has a CPU and RAM and devices that can be attached.

A [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) translates program (source) code into [machine code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_code), where the program code & data are encoded as numbers — see also [Instruction Set Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture).

An [operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating_system) loads (see [loader](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loader_(computing))) the machine code into a process, and starts the CPU at its beginning.

The CPU is hardware that interprets numbers as machine code instructions, and these tell it what to do every step of the machine code program, and at every step, what the next machine code instruction shall be.

Some machine code instructions tell the computer to load or store data in memory, or, to communicate with a device.  There is also an [interrupt mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interrupt) that allows devices to get the attention of the CPU.

This process is very meta, since the CPU is doing this same interpretation of machine code during compiling, linking, and running the operating system — there are mechanisms like [context switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) that allow the CPU to switch jobs/programs and play different roles (operating system, user process A, B, etc..).  Except when idle, the CPU is always executing some program, which is to say some sequence of programmed steps as machine code instructions.

Transistors implement the CPU and the RAM.  Inside the CPU there are functional units for doing, say, addition, subtraction, conditional branching, etc..  These functional units are composed of large numbers of transistors.  The CPU also has register memories and caches.  They all switch values based on the machine code instruction(s) being executed at the moment, as the only job of the CPU is to execute machine code instruction after instruction.

For example, let's say the machine code program instructs the computer to add two numbers that happen to be in CPU registers and write the answer back to one of them.  The hardware will first fetch the instruction to execute, then decode the numbers in it, extract values from the named registers, feed those to the inputs of an [ALU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_logic_unit), instruct that ALU to perform an add, then store the ALU's output back into a register — ready for the next machine code instruction.

We also know that an add can be performed by lots of though very simple boolean logic that transistors can do, see [adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Binary_adders).  This same idea of assembling transistors into function units as needed for a CPU to interpret machine code instructions is done for all features of the processor.

Most digital circuits are built using one single kind of gate, today, the [NAND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_gate) gate.  Gates can be arranged to implement any boolean function.  These transistors are arranged into two broad kinds of circuits: [combinational](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinational_logic) and [sequential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_logic).  While combinational circuits compute output values solely based on provided inputs, sequential circuits have a feedback loop that enables them to remember things.  Designers alternate combinational circuits and sequential circuits to form the functional units of the CPU.  To oversimplify, registers and memory are made using sequential logic, while ALUs will use combinational logic.

You can also check out [RAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory), and how that is constructed also out of transistors.

We can also note that during any given set of machine code instructions being executed, some of the circuitry goes unused, and thus we don't care whether those transistors flip or flop unless trying to save power; other transistors are expected to simply hold their state as is, such as for registers and RAM that are not involved in current machine code instructions.

Comment: *Most digital circuits are built using one single kind of gate, today, the NAND gate.* Really?  It's *possible* to build any other kind of gate out of NAND gates, but can't you build a full adder with fewer transistors if you don't don't limit yourself to just NAND gates?  That seems like a surprising claim.

Answer (score 1):

First off this is massively broad, to truly get it even a four year electrical engineering course, only covers the toolbox of the basics needed to get started trying to understand everything.  Clearly not something that will fit in any SE answer.

If you want to know the physical electronics, then the task of compiling is irrelevant, not remotely related to the question.

CPUs are incredibly stupid: they are state machines that operate on bits that come in.  Your computer has many layers of software that in some ways hide lower layer physical items like the possibly ways to get at storage, usb, pcie hard drive controllers and so on.  USB alone, the old 1.1 spec was 300 printed pages. More than would fit here, and that doesn't cover any details with respect to the flash technologies nor usb to sata or other.

The cpu is fed machine code from requests on its bus,  the requests on its bus are decoded by a memory controller or multiple depending on the design.  Through layers of bussing, a discussion that would fit in a single answer here, various peripherals are addressed, usb controller, pcie controller, dram controller, etc.  Then usually via the pcie controller you have hard disk or other non volatile media these days.  So a very large number of instructions provide a layer that allows the kernel to access a particular hard drive, plus countless more on top of that to create a file system on top of the storing and retrieving bits from the media.

A compiler or assembler or linker, etc are going to be another layer of software on top of the kernel/driver layers on top of the hardware layers to access bytes from the files on the media.  in the compiler case it reads the bytes considered ascii characters, it has software that parses those bytes decoding the defined language, and then using tables generally it grinds on that information reducing the program into smaller pieces .

x = y + 5;

You have at least two variables that need storage (assuming no optimization that removes dead code, before you can reduce the dead code you still have to go through this process).  so at a minimum there has to be a read of the y variable generation of a 5, an addition step with some intermediate result and then storing that intermediate result to the destination.  The compiler is going to grind on lines of code like this to break it into these types of operations.

then there may be an optimzation step, for example the compiler may realize that nowhere does the program use the x variable after this line of code, so this line of code provides no value, it is dead code so all of the steps related to this line of code can go away, get optimized out.  today this is done in ram generally but could have intermediate files created to store information being crunched on.

Understand again all of this code is machine code and data that is going over busses, through caches, from larger memories probably dram based, all of which is one to many semesters of classes to fully understand,  high level understanding not so much.

The front end of the compiler converts the ascii into some internal language/tables, the middle part of the compiler can/does crunch this further, do optimizations, etc.  at this point the compiler might save an intermediate file or one popular compiler has a file format and binary format that you can compile to this stage, to have the backend conversion to the target instruction set done later.

the backend of the compiler then converts the sequences of operations into a series of instructions that the target supports.  you may or may not have a peephole optimizer which is a target specific optimization, for example the target instruction set might offer a register = regsiter + immediate instruction where 5 is a possible immediate rather than register = 5; register = register + register.  once this is done then the output which for sanity sake is assembly language, but there are compilers that output machine/object files.

writing an ascii file is just writing bytes to a file so you have the layers of hardware the layers of operating system plus the layers of language libraries then your application that does the equivalent of an fprintf() to output the ascii characters that represent the assembly language including labels and directives.  If an object and machine code then it is almost identical from a physical perspective just different bytes being generated that represent the object file format and the machine code.

the assembler is the same just a little simpler it also reads through all the layers the bytes which are ascii characters, parses them, etc.  being a different language it is more focused on the labels and such and the individual instructions which tell the assembler the bits to use in the machine code for lines that are instructions.  the assembler again uses temporary files or tables in memory to keep track of this information.  The crunching of data is different from a compiler but there is still a fair amount of work, the instruction set has relative offsets and things that have to be computed as each instruction starts to take form the distance from one instruction to many later can take many iterations.

And through the software layers the assembler then writes the object file.

the linker then takes object files and some set of rules that define the physical address space at least from the view at this stage, from the final execution of the program it is likely a virtual address, but it is an address space told to the linker in some way, often some other file in a format that has to be parsed like a program into tables, etc, using the layers of software and hardware to get bytes from the media that make up that linker script.

Then the linker using all the layers reads bytes from the media which are objects.  external functions for example between two say .C files have to be resolved at this point as the linker places the objects into a virtual copy of the target memory space, where each of these labels lands finally gets its address, then the objects that refer to this label can be patched up by the linker, depending on the overall toolchain design the linker sometimes generates extra code or creates/modifies instructions left by the assembler to facilitate these object connections.

And like all the other programs here it goes through the software and hardware layers to write the bytes to the filesystem which in this case is the final binary, noting that most of the time the final binary is not just a memory image of the program to be loaded and run, it has a file structure just like a document or image file would have with some overhead as well as the binary blobs that have to be loaded into memory for the program being created to run.

Comment: Thank you for your help. What I meant by my basic understanding is that I have a sort of "explain-it-in-a-hand-waving-manner"-level of understanding on the subject. Similarly as in math we take many abstract nonlinear functions for granted, but on the physical domain they are approximated by infinite series of simple calculations.

Comment: wikipedia can cover the basics.  digital logic uses a transistor as a switch.  a transistor can be used as an amplifier in its linear range, but as a switch you are basically banging it on its (power) rails (ground and the supply voltage).   Then from that you can find the logic gate pages that cover AND gates, OR gates, NOT gates, etc generally using two transistors.  Add a crystal oscillator and thats it,  and, or, not plus a clock and you have the minimal building blocks to build a processor, memory controller, etc.

Comment: Put four transistors, two gates, in the right feedback pattern and you have SRAM, I would assume this is also on wikipedia would have to check.   Dram is a different beast it essentially relies on the capacitance in a certain type of transistor, a capacitor should be covered on wikipedia as well.  Think of it is a poor quality battery to store a one lets say then you want to keep that cap charged, to store a zero, empty.  But because of how fast it drains you have to constantly "refresh" the dram, charging up the caps that need to stay charged and not the ones that dont.

Comment: dram lets you get down to one or two transistors per bit rather than the 4 per bit for sram, but you have to have refresh cycles very often as well as how you read/sense the bit is not as simple as sram.

Comment: there is analog I am hand waving over for some of this but mostly the interfaces, the pins, traces, cables, etc.  plus storage media which comes in various technologies, mostly some form of analog technology.  The digital part when the analog hardware is properly configured (Transistors, etc) is no more complicated than AND, OR, NOT combined with a clock.

Comment: also on wikipedia you can look up boolean logic, whose fundamentals and equations are how you combine the AND, OR, NOT into doing real work for us.

Comment: Petzold wrote a book called Code: The Hidden Language of Computer Hardware and Software.  To be honest I didnt read the whole book, I know how they work.  But the parts I read were well done in how he explains it in a way that most everyone could understand.  Might help you might not.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for the info, appreciate it :-) Hope my question helps also wider audience.